# 2 foreign key на одну и туже таблицу

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть в БД сущность `Package`, хочу также хранить дубликаты этой сущности.

**Package:**

```
public class Package
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Duplicate> Duplicates { get; set; }
}
```

**Duplicate:**

```
public class Duplicate
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public ulong PackageAId { get; set; }
    public ulong PackageBId { get; set; }
    public byte MatchPercent { get; set; }

    public Package PackageA { get; set; }
    public Package PackageB { get; set; }
}
```

**Конфигурация Duplicate:**

```
internal class DuplicateConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Duplicate>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Duplicate> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.PackageA)
            .WithMany(x => x.Duplicates)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PackageAId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .HasConstraintName("fk_duplicates_packages_a");

        builder.HasOne(x => x.PackageB)
            .WithMany(x => x.Duplicates)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PackageBId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .HasConstraintName("fk_duplicates_packages_b");
    }
}
```

При создании миграции получаю такую ошибку:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Package.Duplicates' and
>   'Duplicate.PackageB', because there already is a relationship between
>   'Package.Duplicates' and 'Duplicate.PackageA'. Navigation properties
>   can only participate in a single relationship.

Как правильно создать связи между таблицами?

Comment: ну раз у вас 2 внешних ключа, то у вас и две соответствующие коллекции должно быть

Comment: Я это понимаю, но какие это должны быть коллекции и как ими пользоваться в контексте дубликатов? При добавлении дубликата к пакету в какую коллекцию заносить или при получении дубликатов из какой коллекции брать?..

Comment: `public ICollection<Duplicate> DuplicatesA { get; set; }` и `public ICollection<Duplicate> DuplicatesB { get; set; }` чем не устраивают? Для меня это вроде очевидно, потому не могу понять ваш вопрос.